# How to use the word "cabin" and make sure you're referring to the sleeping place in a boat/ship?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Example sentence:

> He rented a __ room in a Japanese Internet cafe.

If you write cabin, there could be two way of seeing it: that the room was shaped like the sleeping place of a boat (which is the intended meaning) or that it's shaped like the room in a cabin in the forest.

Is there a less ambiguous word or a clearer way of phrasing it?

Comment: The word cabin here is incorrect. Surely, you mean a booth. And in your sentence, it cannot mean: shaped like a room.

Comment: It would be easier to give you an answer if we knew exactly what you meant.  Which meaning do you want it to have?

Comment: If one puts the word cabin in the sentence as given: He rented a cabin, makes no sense. I suspect the OP speaks a Romance language where booth is cabine or cabina. So, the question is based on a "false friend".

Comment: @Lambie Oh yeah, my mother tongue is Spanish.

Comment: @Lambie: Some Japanese Internet cafes have cubicles that can be rented, and that are suitable for sleeping in if you are pushed for choice. I think _cabin_ is an appropriate term for such cubicles.

Comment: Cabine and cabina are booth, respectively in French and Spanish. In English, the word cabin does not work here. What is the matter with the English speakers? There are no indoor cabins except on ships.

Comment: @Lambie What I intend to write is a "cabin-themed" room. Didn't state that clearly.

Comment: I feel like you are playing a game. A cabin-themed room does not make much sense in English. It's ambiguous and there is no way to lift that ambiguity if you only use the word cabin. Also, I don't understand why the word berth versus cabin is even relevant here. The Japanese call these rooms: booths. http://disposableworkers.com/?page_id=37 and again: "your own little private booth" http://www.supercheapjapan.com/internet-cafe-accommodation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Berth"** - Did you mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berth_(sleeping)?

> A berth is a bed or sleeping accommodation on vehicles. Space
>   accommodations have contributed to certain common design elements of
>   berths.

A **'cabin'** is usually **a private room on a ship for a passenger or one of the people working on the ship**

**"berth"** - a bed on a train or ship. It is often in the aft cabin. See: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/parts-of-boats-and-ships